# Nagios Core Open Source Monitoring

Tags: nagios3

Where is the HTML file of the "Service Status Details For All Host Groups" page in nagios core on Ubuntu 14.04?

If I want to modify the page (e.g: delete the columns), where can I look up the php file of this page?

Comment: Is this a php file or an HTML file? You mention both.

Comment: You should ask this in a Nagios forum, not on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @SorenA why? This is perfectly on topic here. It is not very clear and Romiz would help if they edited and clarified what they need, but it isn't off topic.

Comment: @terdon I think both of files, because i need to modify the coloumns  in "Service Status Details For All Host Groups" page.